# How to get unique elements using pipe in angular 4

Tags: angular, filter, pipe, unique

[image]I have my facilityListArray as below and I have clinicServices array inside it and I want to filter only unique elements from this clinicServices (get unique parentName object )  array list. Below is the screen shot of facilityListArray. In the attached image, I have shown the expanded list for first array list which has list of clinicService. Similarly inside second list, I have list of clinicServices which has duplicates of the first list. So i want to get only unique clincServices from entire list of array.[image]

Below is my pipe file:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'removeduplicate'
})
export class RemoveduplicatePipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    // Remove the duplicate elements
    const art = value.map( x => {
        return x.clinicServices.map(y => {
            return y.value;
        });
    }).reduce((acc, ele, i) => {
        acc = acc.concat(ele);
        return acc;
    });
    return new Set(art);
}
}
```

HTML code Using Pipe :

```
 <div class="col-sm-12 required" *ngFor="let facilitySearchResult of facilityListArray | removeduplicate">

                                    <label class="container">
                                      <input type="checkbox">{{facilitySearchResult}}
                                      <span class="checkmark"></span>
                                    </label>
                                  </div>
```

HTML code without pipe:

If i use the below code without pipe, I am getting list if clinicService properly but with duplicate elementes. So i implemented the above Pipe code and used that in my HTML as above, but it doesnt work. I am getting empty list with above code . Any help is highly appreciated.

```
 <div class="col-sm-12 required" *ngFor="let facilitySearchResult of facilityListArray; let i=index">
                                <div class="col-sm-12 required" *ngFor="let facilityServiceResult of facilitySearchResult.clinicServices; let j=index">
                                  <label class="container">
                                    <input type="checkbox">{{facilityServiceResult.parentName}}
                                    <span class="checkmark"></span>
                                  </label>
                                </div>
                              </div>
```

Comment: I am unable to figure out what exactly is wrong

Comment: @j4rey89 Can u help me in this question

Comment: This seems far too complicated. Have you tried https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#uniq or https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#uniqBy ?

Comment: I am not sure how to use this

Comment: In your pipe, instead use `return _.uniqBy(value, x=>x.y)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One small error in your `Pipe`

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'removeduplicate'
})
export class RemoveduplicatePipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
        // Remove the duplicate elements
        const art = value.map( x => {
            return x.clinicServices?x.clinicServices.map(y => {
                return y.parentName?y.parentName:null; //<--parentName instead of value
            }):[];
        }).reduce((acc, ele, i) => {
            acc = acc.concat(ele);
            return acc;
        }).filter(z=>{ //<--to filter out null parentNames
            if(z){
                return z;
            }
        });
        return new Set(art);
    }
}
```

And you should be able to get the unique `parentName` of `clinicServices`

Comment: I tried to change to parentName , but it doesnt list the parentName. I have attached the image for you reference.

Comment: what is the error you are encountering? The image you have uploaded only show the line you have set the breakpoint on.

Comment: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null
    at removeduplicate.pipe.ts:11
Also I am not getting any list of parent Names in my application

Comment: very likely that `clinicServices` is null or `parentName` is missing, hence the error. need to handle the errors. I have edited the code.

Comment: Absolutely awesome !! The solution works great now ! ..Thank you so much :)